# npm install not working

Tags: node.js, npm

I just started learning node.js and i have installed node.js along with npm module manager.
I have created a package.json file and from the root directory iam trying to execute npm install command, instead of creating npm_modules folder it throws error like this:

```
C:\Users\username\Desktop\nodetest>npm install
npm WARN package.json backbone-library@0.0.1 No README.md file found!
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mongoose
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/path
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/path
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mongoose
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/path
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mongoose
npm ERR! Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR!     at errnoException (net.js:863:11)
npm ERR!     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:854:19)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>


npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7600
npm ERR! command "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files\\no
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\username\Desktop\nodetest
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.0
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.14
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\username\Desktop\nodetest\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Iam using Windows 7 OS.

Any ideas ?

Thanks,
Srinivas

Comment: It looks like your connection to `registry.npmjs.org` is timing out, for whatever reason.

Comment: are you behind proxy? if yes you need to configure npm to run behind proxy

Comment: Yes. Can you pl tell me how to configure that

Comment: To find the company's proxy: _http://superuser.com/q/346372/443732_

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will probably solve your problem:

```
npm config set proxy proxy-url:port (http:\\proxy-name:port)

npm config set https-proxy proxy-url:port
```

Comment: C:\Users\username\Desktop\nodetest>npm config set proxy http://proxyname.companyname.com:8080  C:\Users\username\Desktop\nodetest>npm config set https-proxy http://proxyname.companyname.com:8080

Comment: try this npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/ than configure proxy.

Comment: Actually i tried in my project root, npm config set registry and then proxy commands. but still npm install doesnt work

Comment: does your proxy required the port ? you have mentioned 8080 so does it is required by your proxy sometimes we just need to give proxy server url not sure but might be it helps.

Comment: btw from your proxy it seems your running it within a company so are you sure you have the right proxy details?

Comment: @sij it works finally on my personal computer since there is no restrictions on https/proxy settings.

Comment: If the proxy require login and password you have to set proxy like http://login:pass@host:port

Answer (score 2):

It was a stuck step on my side,

the following syntax worked for me:

npm config **set proxy** http:/myproxyserver:port

best regards :)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use the windows "run as" command (which is equivalent to the *nix "sudo" command) in order to have the correct privileges on your machine.

This link should be helpful: https://superuser.com/questions/42537/is-there-any-sudo-command-for-windows

Answer (score 1):

finally i came to know that my company laptop has proxy restrictions.Once i got the approval for proxy removal it worked.

Answer (score 1):

But still ppl, who ever facing proxy issue in npm install,can try the following method.

Go to C:\Users\YourUserName 
Create a file named .npmrc (no need of any prefixname just .npmrc)
Inside that file type the following

proxy = username:password@ip:port (add http:// before username)

That's all.It is perfectly working for me....

Answer (score 0):

The traceroute command will usually tell you *where* a connection fails and would have lead you straight to the corporate proxy in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the selected answer

a) "npm config set proxy proxy-url:port (http:\proxy-name:port)

b) npm config set https-proxy proxy-url:port"

make sure you add "http:\\" to your proxy name, and packages downloaded from npm use ssl so try the second option for sure.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are working behind a proxy, configure it:

> npm config set proxy http://login:pass@host:port

2. Check the value of your proxy configuration:

> npm config get http-proxy

3. Try again to get your package...